# Upgrading to Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0 via NuGet fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

Using NuGet, when upgrading to the latest version of ASP.net 5.0.0 I get the following NuGet response:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (= 3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (= 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (= 3.0.0)'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0'.
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc' from version '4.0.30506.0' to '5.0.0' in project 'HotridesMvc'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'AspNetMvc' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0'.
```

Has anyone seen this? I've had a sniff around the old package configuration and don't see anything obviously amiss.

There were a number of other aspnet related updates which have worked, i.e. web-pages, but I'm now left with a broken web-app which shows the yellow screen of death complaining about dll issues.

Answer (score 4):

A key thing here is to update nuget from the command line and not from the UI. The Nuget team is aware of the issue like Nicholas has posted and are looking into it.

Here is a link with the update steps: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this by uninstalling the existing mvc NuGet package I had, and reinstalling, then doing a solution clean build, then rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

According to NuGet Developer danliu "we are working on a fix for this issue, which will be released along with NuGet 2.8."

According to Danliu: One workaround for this issue is to go to update tab, click Update button to Microsoft.Net.Http package first. When it's done, then click the UpdateAll button.

I have been unable to confirm if this works.

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3651

Comment: can confirm this worked for me (after upgrading to latest NuGet as previous version gave an error). thanks!

Comment: Did the above and then also Uninstall-Package AspNetMvc which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue is raised here: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3651, though I am still trying resolve things, have not been as lucky as you, that a simple uninstall of the MVC package, project clean, and then re-install, fixed the problems.

With a bran new ASP.NET MVC 4 project ('TestASP'), then immediately selecting Update All in nuget (which tries to update to MVC 5 and Web Api 2), here's is the full nuget log, with the error at the bottom:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (≥ 3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc (≥ 5.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (≥ 3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 3.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.4)'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0'.
'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0' already installed.
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.0.0' already installed.
'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0' already installed.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.3'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.3'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.15'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.15'.
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc' from version '4.0.30506.0' to '5.0.0' in project 'TestASP'.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 1.0.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 1.0.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0' to TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.0.0' to TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 1.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes 1.0.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.30506.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.30506.0'.
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes' in project 'TestASP'.
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor' in project 'TestASP'.
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi' from version '4.0.30506.0' to '5.0.0' in project 'TestASP'.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.30506.0' from TestASP.
Removing 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0' from TestASP.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0' from TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0' to TestASP.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.30506.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.30506.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.30506.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.30506.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.30506.0'.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0'.
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' in project 'TestASP'.
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core' in project 'TestASP'.
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost' in project 'TestASP'.
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages' in project 'TestASP'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
TestASP does not reference 'Microsoft.Net.Http'.
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was undo all changes in tfs so that it never looked like I tried to update. Then I changed the .net framework on all projects in my solution to .net framework 4.5.1. Then I ran the update and everything worked.